# Deploying a multi-container application to Azure Kubernetes Services without using Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-aks

Deploying a multi-container application to Azure Kubernetes Services without using Azure DevOps
We have use case with Java Application (Spring ) with oracle Database as two containers .
We have to try the same in AKS ( Not using Azure DevOps).

Both App (8080) and DB (1521) runs on different Ports

Let me know if you have similar use case implemented.

Answer (score 1):

The point of discussion here might be that whether you want to use a CI/CD Tool other than Azure Devops or not?

If yes, you'll need to setup a pipeline, write some Kubernetes Templates, Build Code, Push Image, and then deploy.

You can always refer [Kubernetes Official Docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/home/) for more in depth knowledge of Multi-Container Pods, and [Jenkins Official Docs](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/) for understanding CI/CD Process